# Connection String for a local database across multiple users

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

How do you use the connection string on a local database in a way that would allow you to transfer the project folder from one computer to another, without having to modify the connection string?

**Not like this**

```
connection_String As String = "Data Source=C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\CSCI_388_Group_Project\CSCI_388_Group_Project\CSCI_388_Group_Project\CSCI_388_Group_Project_Database.sdf"
```

**More like this**

```
connection_String As String = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CSCI_388_Group_Project_Database.sdf"
```

If I try to enter the second example into the connection field under the database properties I get an illegal character error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class contains most of the paths you'll need.

You can call [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) to get a special directory. For example, to get the *My Documents* directory, call `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`.

You can browse all of the special folders here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

In your example specifically, you'd use the following:

```vb
connection_String As String = _
    "Data Source=" & 
    Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
        "CSCI_388_Group_Project_Database.sdf" )
```

*Alternative:*
Is it possible to just ask the user? If it's on their desktop, they might move it.

Comment: Appreciate it, tried to figure it out on my own first but was struggling with where to look. These examples will definitely push me in the right direction.

Comment: I only learned of this class a few months ago, and I've been programming in .NET for nearly 10 years. It's not a well-known one. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for saving me some time messing around with it ;) And I can believe that you are still learning a decade later, there is a lot of information to try and absorb! I suppose that could make it more interesting though.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to keep the `sdf` file in the same folder in which your `exe` would reside, then you can do like this.

```
Dim ExeFolder As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Dim connection_String As String = "Data Source=" & ExeFolder & "CSCI_388_Group_Project_Database.sdf"
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use an environment variable to specify your path to the folder.

Then in your VB program using the [Environ function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fx287h4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get the environment variable settings and use string manipulation to build your connect string.

You will need to have a default in case the environment variable is not set.

However when you launch your application, you can do it within a script that will set the environment variable.

A second method is to specify the path name on the application command line so that when the application is launched, it will specify the path using the command line.

A third method is to have a Windows registry key that you use.  Then, similar to the environment variable, you query the Windows Registry for the folder path, then build your connect string from that.

With this third method you can have your application installer insert the Registry key.

A fourth method is to have an .ini file that contains an entry for the folder path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am sure one of them will work perfectly for this situation.